# Problem with TinyMCE Upload Image with Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce, image-upload

Currently I'm using this proyect [ckeditor5-build-laravel-image](https://github.com/shino47/ckeditor5-build-laravel-image) and I'm getting the following error

> [Failed to upload image: HTTP Error:500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4bWu.png)

I checked the routes, the controller and I can't find the problem. I'm pretty new in Laravel so I don't quite understand what is the problem actually.

This is the upload function:

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{
    $imgpath = $request->file('file')->store('post', 'public');
    return response()->json(['location' => "/storage/$imgpath"]);
}
```

I'm doing something wrong or I miss something?

Comment: check your laravel logs it is mostly in storage/logs with a .log extension

Comment: I check and I found a problem, fopen(): Filename cannot be empty {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fopen(): Filename cannot be empty at C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\www\\tinymce-laravel-master\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemAdapter.php:254) I had the same problem before after I changed my PHP version from 7.2.19 to 7.4.12, I haven't been able to fix it yet

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, my problem was with Laragon and the php.ini, I changed the **upload_tmp_dir** settings to `upload_tmp_dir = C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Temp` and that solve my issue. It was all in a simple permission problem, so to avoid modifying an unnecessary permission, change the path and voila.

Comment: it is strange I have hardly heard that windows need permissions